# ios converting project to arc

Tags: ios, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

Let's assume that i have a method that looks like this.

```
-(void)doSmth {
    NSString *one = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",someNumber];

    NSString *two = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",someOtherNumer];

    [one release];
}
```

Project was created without ARC.
I would like to convert it to ARC.

My question is: will there be leaks after converting to arc?

Thanks

Comment: With or without ARC, those `[[NSString alloc] init]` initializers are redundant. You assign a different string to each variable on the very next line, so there was no reason to create and assign an empty string first.

Comment: I've edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ARC converter will remove the explicit call to `release`, and the compiler will automatically insert release calls for both `one` and `two` at compile time.

End result: no leaks here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove `[one release];` as in ARC this generates an error.

With regards to your question, after switching to ARC (and removing the release statement) it will not leak.

Edit:
It would probably be better to write the code like this:

```
NSString *one = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat@"one"];
```

or like this:

```
NSString *one = @"one";
```

Comment: "...no it will not leak." - it most certainly *will* leak if you don't implement it properly.

Comment: I didn't start the project. And it's full of leaks. It has classes in which some objects are released and some aren't. This is why i was asking if there will be after converting to arc

Comment: @EvanMulawski The code he wrote above, after removing the release statement, will not leak in ARC.  There are certainly ways to leak memory in ARC, but the above code won't

Comment: better use `NSString *one=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"one"];` (it's faster..and easier)

Comment: @user1078065 Ah, I see.  Well good on you that you didn't write that code!  It most certainly would be leaky and have possible crashes too.

Comment: what about adding the -fno-objc-arc flag to a class that has both released and unreleased objects? Will it leak?

Comment: @user1078065: If you use -fno-objc-arc, then you're back in manual-reference-counting mode, and all [the usual rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) apply. “both released and unreleased objects” doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok. That's what i was asking/searching for. A class has an obj A that is created and not released and an object B created and released = "both released and unreleased objects"

Comment: This code would not leak anyway, you don't need to release nsstring objects pre arc

Comment: initWithFormat: doesn't return an autoreleased object

Comment: @user1078065 I know. If you are using ARC, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @GregPrice: You do if you created them with `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if we need to convert to complete project to ARC  then Edit ->convert -> to Objective-C ARC

or if u need to convert a particular file then projectNav ->build Phases ->compile source in that particular .m file add -fno-objc-arc

[image]